# Generate Excel File with specific group of output

Tags: php

Can someone or somebody help me with my code or with my SQL execution? I'd like to create an excel file based on a specific group of data based on the event/activity they participated in.

Here is my code:

```
$program_admin = $_SESSION['username'];
$actvty_ID = $_POST['id'];
//$activitydate = $_POST['activity_date'];

if(isset($_POST['export_in_excel'])) {
    $excel_sql = "SELECT *
                  FROM projectcode pj
                  INNER JOIN activities ac ON ac.projects_id = pj.projects_id
                  INNER JOIN participants re ON re.act_id = ac.id
                  WHERE pj.project_code='$program_admin'
                  ORDER BY re.id DESC "; //pj.project_code='$program_admin'
   
    $excel_result = mysqli_query($connect, $excel_sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($excel_result) > 0) {
        $excel_output .='
        <table class="excel_table" style="font-family:Calibri; border:1px solid #1f004d;">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d;">No.</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d;">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Age</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Gender</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">City/Municipality</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Province</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Contact No.</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Email Address</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Organization</th>
                <th style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #1f004d; ">Signature</th>
            </tr>
        ';
        $no = 1;
        while($excel_row = mysqli_fetch_array($excel_result)) {
            $excel_output .='
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;">'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["firstname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["lastname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["agerange"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["gender"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["city_municipality"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["province"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["mobileno"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["email"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$excel_row["org_office"].'</td>
                    <td></td>
                    
                </tr>
            ';
            $no ++;
        }
        $excel_output .='</table>';
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Attendance Sheet.xls");
        echo $excel_output;
        
    }
}
```

And here is the sample output of my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAXgS.png)

Comment: Hi RIn, I'm not sure what you want to achieve and what you already tried and where you are stuck. 

Could you obscure the personal data, if you are using real data?

Comment: Hello @Uwe, It is okay some of my data are just still examples tho it looks like they're real. About the code, it is activity registration system and I want to retrieve the who registered with the specific activity but every time I exported it into excel it includes the registered participants from other activity.

Comment: Hi @Rin, I don't know your db structure but would assume, that you need to add the `$actvty_ID` as part of your where clause in your SQL. Eg. something like `WHERE pj.project_code='$program_admin' and  ac.id = '$actvty_ID'`

As you have to filter for the specific activity and currently it only filters by project_code.